# Getting error when using class in tkinter ? (OOP)

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to display a Options menu which has various options to select. editionMap, topicMap, langMap all are dictionaries. I am trying to make a single options menu and then make instances of it.

```
import tkinter as tk
from utils import editionMap, topicMap, langMap

class OptionMenu:
    """Constructor Function"""
    def __init__(self, master, status, *options):
        self.frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.dropdown = tk.StringVar()
        self.dropdown.set("status")


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    menu1 = OptionMenu(root, "Language", *langMap.keys())
    menu1.pack()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am want to make optionsmenu using classes (see screenshot):

[image]

On creating class OptionMenu I am getting errors and only GUI window opens which is blank

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\KWOC gnewsclient\gnewsclient\gnewsclient\test.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "F:\KWOC gnewsclient\gnewsclient\gnewsclient\test.py", line 18, in main
    menu1.pack()
AttributeError: 'OptionMenu' object has no attribute 'pack'
```

Comment: you need to use `tk.Frame` because that is how you imported tkinter, if you had done `from tkinter import *` (not that i recommend this) then what you have above would work for the frame (but not for your stringvar or root window)

Comment: You need to use `tk.Frame` instead.

Comment: In addition, it should be `self.frame.pack()` not `frame.pack()` in `__init__`

Comment: @j_4321 I have done changes but it gives `StringVar does not have attribute (attribute error)`

Comment: You are trying to pack the `StringVar` with `self.dropdown.pack()`, but it is not a widget.

Comment: @j_4321 Check code I have edited but still error

Comment: @JamesKent I have made necessary changes in code but still giving error

Comment: you biggest mistake - you create own `OptionMenu` but you doesn't use original `tk.OptionMenu` inside.

Comment: @furas If possible can you edit code and tell I am not able to understand

Comment: @bryan Oakley I have edited the question

Comment: @Icefire we can continue the discussion in the chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161035/getting-error-when-using-class-in-tkinter-oop

Comment: Your edit just changes it to be a duplicate of a different question. Please do a little research before asking such basic questions. Simply searching this site for "object has no attribute pack" yields results that might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create own `OptionMenu` with `Frame` inside but without original `tk.OptionMenu`

```
import tkinter as tk

langMap = {1:"English", 2:"German", 3:"Russian"}

class MyOptionMenu1():  # <-- without inheritions it is not widget, 
                        # You can't use `menu1.pack()`.
                        # You could use only `menu1.frame.pack()`.
                        # Or you have to create own `def pack(self, **options)
                        #    and execute `self.frame.pack()` inside

    def __init__(self, master, status, *options):

        self.frame = tk.Frame(master) # <-- tk.
        self.frame.pack() # <-- self.

        self.result = tk.StringVar()
        #self.result.set(status)

        self.label = tk.Label(self.frame, text=status)
        self.label.pack()

        self.dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(self.frame, self.result, *options)
        self.dropdown.pack()


class MyOptionMenu2(tk.Frame): # <-- inherits from Frame

    def __init__(self, master, status, *options):

        super().__init__(master) # Frame constructor
        #self.pack() # <-- without - use `menu1.pack()` to show this frame 

        self.result = tk.StringVar()
        #self.result.set(status)

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text=status) # <-- self as parent/master
        self.label.pack()

        self.dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.result, *options) # <-- self as parent/master
        self.dropdown.pack()


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()

    # --- version 1 ---

    menu1 = MyOptionMenu1(root, "Language", *langMap.keys()) # <-- tk.
    #menu1.pack() # <--- without, because MyOptionMenu1 is not widget

    menu1 = MyOptionMenu1(root, "Language", *langMap.values()) # <-- tk.
    #menu1.pack() # <--- without, because MyOptionMenu1 is not widget

    # --- version 2 ---

    menu1 = MyOptionMenu2(root, "Language", *langMap.keys()) # <-- tk.
    menu1.pack() # <--- with, because MyOptionMenu2 is widget 

    menu1 = MyOptionMenu2(root, "Language", *langMap.values()) # <-- tk.
    menu1.pack() # <--- without, because MyOptionMenu is not widget

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

**EDIT:** code with layout changes but without some comments

```
import tkinter as tk

class MyOptionMenu1(): # <-- not inherits from Frame 

    def __init__(self, master, status, *options):

        self.frame = tk.Frame(master) # internal class
        self.frame.pack(anchor='w') # show in window

        self.result = tk.StringVar(value=options[0])

        self.label = tk.Label(self.frame, text=status)
        self.label.pack(side='left')

        self.dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(self.frame, self.result, *options)
        self.dropdown.pack()


class MyOptionMenu2(tk.Frame): # <-- inherits from Frame

    def __init__(self, master, status, *options):

        super().__init__(master) # Frame constructor
        #self.pack(anchor='w') # show in window (but you can do it outside

        self.result = tk.StringVar(value=options[0])

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text=status) # <-- self as parent/master
        self.label.pack(side='left')

        self.dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.result, *options) # <-- self as parent/master
        self.dropdown.pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    langMap = {1:"English", 2:"German", 3:"Russian"}

    root = tk.Tk()

    # --- version 1 ---

    menu = MyOptionMenu1(root, "Language", *langMap.keys())
    #menu.pack() # <--- without pack(),
                 # because MyOptionMenu1 is not widget
                 # and it doesn't have this method

    menu = MyOptionMenu1(root, "Language", *langMap.values())
    #menu.pack() # <--- without pack(),
                 # because MyOptionMenu1 is not widget
                 # and it doesn't have this method

    # --- version 2 ---

    menu = MyOptionMenu2(root, "Language", *langMap.keys())
    menu.pack(anchor='w') # <--- with pack()
                          # because MyOptionMenu2 is widget 

    menu = MyOptionMenu2(root, "Language", *langMap.values())
    menu.pack(anchor='w') # <--- with pack()
                          # because MyOptionMenu2 is widget

    # --- start ---

    root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: what If I need to use `menu1.pack()`

Comment: you get error message because `menu1` is not widget - you don't use `class MyOption(tk.Frame)`

Comment: see new code in answer

Comment: In version2 we can use `menu1.pack()` because we have not packed `Frame` in our constructor am I right. So if I pack `Frame` and `OptionMenu` is constructor itself then no need to pack in `main` am I right.

Comment: yes, you are right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161042/discussion-between-ice-fire-and-furas).

Comment: BTW: with version2 you can use `menu.grid()` instead `menu.pack()` if you use `grid()` in window. Version1 uses always `self.frame.pack()` so it will make problem if you use  `grid()` in window - you would have to remove `self.frame.pack()` and use `menu.frame.grid()`.

Comment: currently all options are aligned top to bottom I am not able to make them side by side.

Comment: use parameters in `pack()` to change it. ie. `self.label.pack(side="left")`

Comment: You mean `pack(side=tk.LEFT)`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/iEzix

Comment: `tk.LEFT` keeps string `"left" - so you can use `"left"` instead of `tk.LEFT`

Comment: see new code and image

Comment: For centre do I need to use `"centre"`

Comment: to center `Language [ 1 ]` you have to remove `anchor='w'` in `menu.pack(anchor='w')`

Comment: see images on https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/align-grid-pack

Comment: to center only `[ 1 ]` you have to add `fill='x'` in `menu.pack(anchor='w', fill='x')`

Comment: I want to display menu options horizontally in centre of window. `Menu1` `Menu2` `Menu3` like this.

Comment: then use `grid()` to puts every menu in new column. Or use `menu.pack(side='left")` for every menu. See layout managers: [pack](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm) and [grid](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm)

Comment: I didn't visite FB for 2 months - there is too much informations to read. And it displays Python code without indentions and colors.

Comment: email: furas@tlen.pl